# React button not responding to click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

My React button's click is not responding to onClick. I am just doing a simple console.log(), and that is not even working.

The weird thing is that when I also place the button in App.js, the button will click in my other component but not without it. This makes me think it has something to do with how it is being mounted.

In App.js I have the following inside App.js' render() to route to my component (Tweets.js):

```
<div className="App-intro">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/appTweets" render={(props) => <Tweets {...props} tweets="home" />} />
    </Switch>
```

And this is Tweets.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Tweet} from 'react-twitter-widgets';


const TweetList = (props) => {
  console.log('tweet list props');
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>{props.tweets.map(tweet=> <Tweet key={tweet.tweet_id} {...tweet}/>)}
    </div>

  ); 
}


class Tweets extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log("tweet props");
    console.log(props);
    this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      tweets: [],
      selectedPolitician: null,
    }
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log('clicked aoc ');
    console.log(e);
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("fetching the hostname");
    // fetch(HOST_NAME + TWEET_ENDPOINT) 
    var hostname = "";
    if (window.location.hostname === "localhost"){
      hostname = "http://localhost:8000";
    } else {
      hostname = "https://pst-360.herokuapp.com"
    }
    console.log(hostname);
    fetch(hostname + "/tweets/?format=json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result,
          tweets: result.results.map(function(tweet){
            return {"tweetId": tweet.tweet_id};
          })
        });
        console.log("got result!");
        console.log(result);
      }
    )  
  }

   render() {
     return (
     <div className="container-fluid text-center">

  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Alexandria Ocasio Cortex</button>

    <div className="row content">  
    </div>
      <div className="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
        <TweetList tweets={this.state.tweets} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      </div>
  </div>

     )
   }
 }
 export default Tweets
```

Comment: Here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/r4zrkqpyy4 The console message gets logged when I click the button. I didn't change anything except to remove the imports and code references to files that you didn't include in your sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I had an incorrect version of bootstrap in my package.json. 
Changed from 
`"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2"` 
to:
`"bootstrap": "^4.2.1"`

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I could see regarding onClick is that you already did binding for handleClick in constructor so again no need for binding while calling in button onClick. Otherwise everything looks fine button should work please double check

Change

```
   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

To

```
   onClick={this.handleClick}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the problem.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. By looking at the button functionality code you shared should work. Please create reproducible version in codesandbox or stackblitz

Comment: I'm sorry... I cant figure out how to get the React code to work in the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

The codesandbox you provided works fine if you remove the missing files and resolve the dependencies. Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/o53w1nro26.

But you still see the warning messages in console. It's related to how events are handled in React. Maybe this would help you solve your problem in this / future cases.

Whenever you try to handle events within react it returns an instance of **SyntheticEvent**. The reason for this is to improve performance and enable cross browser compatibility. So, the event you receive is different than the actual DOM event and it's not accessible within asynchronous code which might result in error most of the time. So, the correct approach is to extract the values you need from that event into different variables and use that variables instead. e.g

```
handleClick = ({target, value}) => console.log(target, value);
```

Here we are extracting the target and values from the event because React throws a warning if you try to use the event directly.

I hope this helps you out. Feel free to ask if you have any questions. You can learn more about [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be packages related with bootstrap. Try npm install bootstrap.